# Why won't Steam launch properly? And why do I get these error messages?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, steam, opengl

I have indeed set this as standard in the additional drivers settings for my NVIDIA GeForce GTX 780: *Using NVIDIA GeForce binary driver version 311.38 from nvidia-311 (proprietary, tested)*

- This is what Steam says when I try to launch it:

  ```
  OpenGL GLX context is not using direct rendering, which may cause performance problems.
  For more information visit https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9938EYZB-7457
  ```
- Left 4 Dead 2 says this:

  ```
  Could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError'!
  Either your video card is unsupported, or your OpenGL driver needs to be updated.
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to use the driver that says:  propietary-updates.

Comment: Hmm... I can't seem to see what you mentioned :/...

Comment: Goto Preferences/Additional Drivers.  It will ask for a password.  It should load after a bit and show a few drivers. 
The opensource driver and then proprietary drivers.
Choose one the says: Nvidia proprietary-updates

Comment: No idea if that solved my problem, but I still get the same error after selecting nvidia-311-updates... I will reboot and take a look.

Comment: You definitely want to reboot after changing drivers..it helps

Comment: Ok, I owe you a lot Mark! After a whole day, it works! Finally! :D

Comment: Glad to help buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

Proprietary drivers sometimes give strange issues. You usually have a choice of the latest, previous, legacy-updates, legacy-updates.
play around with them and see which one works best for you.

Note that before installing a new driver, there's always the chance that you end up having a black screen... take note how to resolve this issue before you make any changes ;)
Usually going to a terminal (CTRL+ALT+F1), apt-get purge nvidia* and a reboot would do the trick, getting you back to the standard Xorg (nouveau) driver.

Comment: I see. Well, as I cannot post any images yet, I'll have to use my wise words :)